# Off-board connected nets in KiCAD

Tags: kicad

I am creating a PCB which has multiple ground pads which are connected together off-board. Pcbnew however doesn't know this, so it continues to draw white connecting lines between the ground pads, and of course ERC fails.

How do I tell KiCAD that certain pads are connected together "off-board", and thus does not need traces connecting them?

Comment: Would KiCad allow you to create a component with multiple pins, all labelled GND?

Comment: @BrianDrummond yes it would... what next?

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to tell KiCad that the pins are connected elsewhere.  DRC and ERC errors will not prevent the program from producing Gerber files - they are just warnings to you that something doesn't comply with the rules you have given to program.

It is safe to ignore DRC and ERC errors, providing you know why the errors are there, and are certain that they are acceptable.  It is, of course, best if you can clear all errors, but occasionally some errors are unavoidable (or it is too hard to adjust the rules to avoid the errors).